# How to exceed ram limit?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I recently bought a used MacBook (a1181, early 2009) for extremely cheap and I was curious to ask if there was a way to exceed the 4gb ram limit. I was actually trying to get 8gb in it. I know, kind of a dumb question.
It currently has 4gb in it.

I also patched it so it could run OS X High Sierra if that helps any.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't exceed RAM limits.  The logic board can't handle it. You would end up having to replace the logic board.  It becomes so expensive that your better off purchasing a new computer.

Comment: @Josh, I believe the statement you've made in your comment, "You can't exceed RAM limits", to the OP is wrong as a hard fast rule base just on what Apple's figure is on system that have removable RAM. While in some cases your comment may be applicable, it's not in this case! I've found information provided by the two sources,  Mactracker and EveryMac.com to be quite accurate. I too had an older Mac that I was actually able to double the amount of RAM that Apple had stated was the max, and had no issues running with the increased RAM for many years when I finally purchased a new Mac.

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you for your concern. Regardless of what Apple claims to be the max, there is a actual hardware max, based on what the logic board, and possible other hardware, can handle. The max I was referring to was the actual max, not the one according to Apple, if it is indeed incorrect. This max cannot be exceeded (without replacement of hardware). According to your answer the max is 6GB. If this is true then it cannot be exceeded. Hence the “max”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Mactracker](http://mactracker.ca/), your MacBook 13-inch, Early 2009 (A1181, early 2009) can handle 6 GB RAM, or 2 GB more than Apple's 4 GB spec. You'd need to use a combination of a 4 GB and 2 GB [200-pin PC2-5300 (667MHz) DDR2 SO-DIMM](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/macbook-%2813-inch%2C-early-2009%29).

See also: [Apple MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.0 13" (White-09) Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-white-13-early-2009-nvidia-specs.html) at [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com)